# How to OTA update ESP32s3 Wifi Mesh nodes/children?

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

ESP-IDF v5.1+. Fixed Gateway(root).

I'm unable to find examples or documentation on OTA updating WIFI MESH nodes using only ESP-IDF. I have no intention of using ESP-MDF or MESH-LITE as they're out of date and poorly supported for the newer versions of IDF.

My gateway is able to use `esp_https_ota()` and `esp_http_client_perform()` functionality. Is there a solution for a node to use the same wrappers and have the GET request and response forwarded through the gateway?

The firmware versions for the gateway and nodes differ, so I cannot read firmware directly from the gateway's APP partition.
The .bin file is hosted on an EC2 server and works as intended when updating the root using the HTTPS wrappers.